# El texto de un párrafo se solapa

Tags: html5, css3, ios, responsive, mediaqueries

he desarrollado una web con HTML5, CSS3 y Jquery. Está subida y funciona perfectamente, excepto por un fallo que se le ha presentado a un usuario con Iphone 7 y navegando desde Safari. Cuando abre alguna sección de la carta, el texto aparece completamente solapado, haciendo imposible su lectura (adjunto un pantallazo). Lo extraño es que en el resto de dispositivos, incluidos Iphones más recientes, la web se ve perfectamente. ¿Alguien sabe por dónde puedo tirar?

Adjunto el fragmento de código que creo necesario, como veréis es una ventana modal que podéis abrir haciendo click en el texto alternativo de la imagen.

Las soluciones que yo he probado pero parecen no funcionar es añadir un min-heigth al producto o también distintas opciones de white-space.

Yo no consigo reproducir el problema, únicamente se presenta en el Iphone 7.

```js
/* eslint-env jquery */

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".modal-carta").hide();
  $(".alergenos").hide();
  $(".foto-producto").hide();


  $(".cerrar-modal").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
    $(".alergenos").hide();
    $(".foto-producto").hide();
  });

  $(".ver-alergenos").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.alergenos').slideDown();
  });

  $(".ver-foto").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.foto-producto').slideDown();
  });

  $("#desayunos").click(function() {
    $("#modal-desayunos").fadeIn()
  });


});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

h1 {
  font-family: coquette, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-family: coquette, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #75512F;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 22pt;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  hyphens: auto;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}


/* empiezan estilos carta */

.categoria {
  width: 25%;
  height: 40vh;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.categoria>figure {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.categoria>figure>img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.modal-carta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 88%;
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px) saturate(110%) brightness(100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-carta>div {
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 90%;
  border: solid thin #F6A963;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.cerrar-modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cerrar-modal>span {
  font-size: 30pt;
  color: #F6A963;
}

.cerrar-modal:hover>span {
  color: #228DA8;
}

.foto-seccion {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100% - 8rem);
  min-height: 33vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.foto-seccion>img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.modal-carta>div>h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F6A963;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.modal-carta>div>h4 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.producto {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 4rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.modal-carta>div>.producto:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.nombre-y-precio {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: #75512F;
}

.nombre-producto {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 11pt;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  font-family: montserrat;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.precio-producto {
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

.descripcion-producto>p {
  color: #75512F;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-family: montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

.mas-informacion-producto {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.mas-informacion-producto>button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
  color: #F6A963;
  line-height: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  border: solid thin #F6A963;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.mas-informacion-producto>button:hover {
  background-color: #228DA8;
  color: white;
}

.alergenos {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3vh;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.alergenos>img {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.foto-producto {
  display: flex;
  height: 25vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.foto-producto>img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.subtitular-carta {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}


/* acaban estilos carta */


/* empiezan media queries móvil */

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  p {
    font-size: 10pt;
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 20pt;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 18pt;
  }
  main {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  /*    empiezan media queries carta*/
  #contenedor-categorias {
    height: auto;
  }
  .categoria {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1rem;
  }
  .modal-carta {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
  }
  .modal-carta>div {
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  }
  .cerrar-modal {
    background: none;
  }
  #modal-cafes>div>.cerrar-modal>span {
    color: #228DA8;
  }
  .foto-seccion {
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
  .producto {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: auto;
  }
  .descripcion-producto>p {
    white-space: normal;
  }
  .alergenos>img {
    height: 4vh;
  }
  /*    acaban media queries carta*/
}


/* acaban media queries móvil */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Carta | Feria83</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/trt8csw.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>

  <main id="main-carta">

    <section id="contenedor-categorias">

      <div class="categoria" id="desayunos">

        <figure>
          <img class="estatica" src="../img/carta/desayunos.jpg" alt="Desayunos">
        </figure>

      </div>

      <section class="modal-carta" id="modal-desayunos">

        <div>

          <button class="cerrar-modal"><span class="material-icons">cancel</span></button>

          <figure class="foto-seccion">
            <img src="../img/carta/cabecera-desayunos.jpg" alt="Tostadas con base de queso crema, naranjas y huevo duro">
          </figure>

          <h2 class="titulo-seccion">Desayunos</h2>
          <h3>Servido de 9:00 a 12:00</h3>
          <h4>Pregunta por nuestro pan sin gluten</h4>


          <div class="producto">

            <div class="nombre-y-precio">
              <h3 class="nombre-producto">Tostadas</h3>
              <p class="precio-producto">2,00€</p>
            </div>

            <div class="descripcion-producto">
              <p>Nuestras tostadas de siempre a elegir entre pan blanco, semillas o 100% integral con mantequilla y mermelada casera o aceite y tomate. </p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="producto">

            <div class="nombre-y-precio">
              <h3 class="nombre-producto">Mollete de Cúrcuma con aguacate, Salmon y huevo escalfado</h3>
              <p class="precio-producto">5,00€</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="producto">

            <div class="nombre-y-precio">
              <h3 class="nombre-producto">Mollete de tomate con hummus casero, carne mechada y cebolla caramelizada</h3>
              <p class="precio-producto">5,00€</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="producto">

            <div class="nombre-y-precio">
              <h3 class="nombre-producto">Rebanada de centeno con base de crema de queso y naranja con huevo duro</h3>
              <p class="precio-producto">5,00€</p>
            </div>

            <div class="mas-informacion-producto">

              <button class="ver-foto">Ver foto</button>

              <figure class="foto-producto">
                <img src="../img/carta/tostada-naranja.jpg" alt="Tostada con naranja, huevo duro y queso">
              </figure>

            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="producto">

            <div class="nombre-y-precio">
              <h3 class="nombre-producto">Rebanada de pan blanco, con Bacon, queso cheddar derretido y huevo frito</h3>
              <p class="precio-producto">5,00€</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="producto">

            <div class="nombre-y-precio">
              <h3 class="nombre-producto">Rebanada de nueces con crema de cacahuete, plátano y canela</h3>
              <p class="precio-producto">5,00€</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="producto">

            <div class="nombre-y-precio">
              <h3 class="nombre-producto">Croissant casero relleno de queso, jamón de york y huevos revueltos</h3>
              <p class="precio-producto">5,00€</p>
            </div>

          </div>

          <h2 class="subtitular-carta">Extras</h2>

          <div class="producto">

            <div class="nombre-y-precio">
              <h3 class="nombre-producto">Jamón de york, pavo, queso edam</h3>
              <p class="precio-producto">0,50€</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="producto">

            <div class="nombre-y-precio">
              <h3 class="nombre-producto">Aguacate, jamón ibérico, queso fresco de cabra, bacon</h3>
              <p class="precio-producto">1,00€</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="producto">

            <div class="nombre-y-precio">
              <h3 class="nombre-producto">Huevos revueltos, Salmon, bolw de fruta fresca, Yogurt natural</h3>
              <p class="precio-producto">2,00€</p>
            </div>

          </div>


        </div>


      </section>

    </section>

  </main>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/script.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

La web la podéis visitar en: https://www.feria83.com

Muchas gracias,

Pedro

[image: Pantallazo del error]

Comment: Para poder ayudarte debes incluir un [mcve]. Una imagen sólo ayuda a ver el problema que describes, pero es necesario el código en formato texto y no un enlace externo. Por otro lado, ¿qué has intentado para resolver el problema? Saludos

Comment: Gracias por las indicaciones Mauricio, he actualizado el post añadiendo tus sugerencias.

Comment: Qué versión de iOS tienen en el iPhone 7? Acabo de mirar el menú en Safari en un iPhone XS, en el simulador de iPhone 7, 11 y funciona perfecto. La versión de iOS de los simuladores es 15.2.

Comment: Hola! Perdón por la tardanza, como no es mi iphone ha tardado la chica en decirmelo. Es la versión 13.3.1.